# How to remedy the fail of Gmail's Print on a message in a new window?

Tags: gmail, google-chrome

In Gmail, I use:

[image]

and then

[image]

but get this fail

[image]

despite Settings

[image]

How can I remedy this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because troubleshooting like questions are off-topic in Web Applications Stack Exchange.

Comment: Should have been migrated to SU instead of being closed.

Answer (score 0):

Settings:

[image]

("Body must be at least 30 characters" says this form. Good grief!)